# Error compiling Arduino

Tags: compile

I've just installed the last version of Arduino 1.6.7 plug my Arduino SmartEverything (http://www.smarteverything.it/) to OS X 10.11.2, try to compile this project: https://github.com/nicolsc/sigfox-weather-station/blob/master/sigfox_smart_weather.ino But i got this error

```
/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/arduino-builder -dump-prefs -logger=machine -hardware "/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware" -hardware "/Users/nunito/Library/Arduino15/packages" -tools "/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/tools-builder" -tools "/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr" -tools "/Users/nunito/Library/Arduino15/packages" -built-in-libraries "/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/libraries" -libraries "/Users/nunito/Documents/Arduino/libraries" -fqbn=AMEL:samd:AMEL_SmartEverything_native -vid-pid=0X2341_0XE002 -ide-version=10607 -build-path "/var/folders/52/_nghc_ms7p52tqr5zdbwvj240000gn/T/build50d3a89dbbfb2b67c903ba23d4913431.tmp" -warnings=none -prefs=build.warn_data_percentage=75 -verbose "/var/folders/52/_nghc_ms7p52tqr5zdbwvj240000gn/T/arduino_50d3a89dbbfb2b67c903ba23d4913431/sketch_jan21c.ino"
/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/arduino-builder -compile -logger=machine -hardware "/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware" -hardware "/Users/nunito/Library/Arduino15/packages" -tools "/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/tools-builder" -tools "/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr" -tools "/Users/nunito/Library/Arduino15/packages" -built-in-libraries "/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/libraries" -libraries "/Users/nunito/Documents/Arduino/libraries" -fqbn=AMEL:samd:AMEL_SmartEverything_native -vid-pid=0X2341_0XE002 -ide-version=10607 -build-path "/var/folders/52/_nghc_ms7p52tqr5zdbwvj240000gn/T/build50d3a89dbbfb2b67c903ba23d4913431.tmp" -warnings=none -prefs=build.warn_data_percentage=75 -verbose "/var/folders/52/_nghc_ms7p52tqr5zdbwvj240000gn/T/arduino_50d3a89dbbfb2b67c903ba23d4913431/sketch_jan21c.ino"
Build options changed, rebuilding all
""   -w -x c++ -E -CC -DF_CPU=48000000L -DARDUINO=10607 -DARDUINO_SAMD_SMARTEVERYTHING -DARDUINO_ARCH_SAMD  -D__SAMD21J18A__        "-I/Users/nunito/Library/Arduino15/packages/AMEL/hardware/samd/1.1.0/cores/arduino" "-I/Users/nunito/Library/Arduino15/packages/AMEL/hardware/samd/1.1.0/variants/AMEL_SmartEverything" "/var/folders/52/_nghc_ms7p52tqr5zdbwvj240000gn/T/build50d3a89dbbfb2b67c903ba23d4913431.tmp/sketch/sketch_jan21c.ino.cpp" -o "/dev/null"
""   -w -x c++ -E -CC -DF_CPU=48000000L -DARDUINO=10607 -DARDUINO_SAMD_SMARTEVERYTHING -DARDUINO_ARCH_SAMD  -D__SAMD21J18A__        "-I/Users/nunito/Library/Arduino15/packages/AMEL/hardware/samd/1.1.0/cores/arduino" "-I/Users/nunito/Library/Arduino15/packages/AMEL/hardware/samd/1.1.0/variants/AMEL_SmartEverything" "/var/folders/52/_nghc_ms7p52tqr5zdbwvj240000gn/T/build50d3a89dbbfb2b67c903ba23d4913431.tmp/sketch/sketch_jan21c.ino.cpp" -o "/dev/null"
""   -w -x c++ -E -CC -DF_CPU=48000000L -DARDUINO=10607 -DARDUINO_SAMD_SMARTEVERYTHING -DARDUINO_ARCH_SAMD  -D__SAMD21J18A__        "-I/Users/nunito/Library/Arduino15/packages/AMEL/hardware/samd/1.1.0/cores/arduino" "-I/Users/nunito/Library/Arduino15/packages/AMEL/hardware/samd/1.1.0/variants/AMEL_SmartEverything" "/var/folders/52/_nghc_ms7p52tqr5zdbwvj240000gn/T/build50d3a89dbbfb2b67c903ba23d4913431.tmp/sketch/sketch_jan21c.ino.cpp" -o "/var/folders/52/_nghc_ms7p52tqr5zdbwvj240000gn/T/build50d3a89dbbfb2b67c903ba23d4913431.tmp/preproc/ctags_target_for_gcc_minus_e.cpp"
exec: "-w": executable file not found in $PATH
Error compiling.
```

[image]

Comment: Your installation is broken.

Comment: I've reinstalled Arduino with the same problem

Comment: You must reinstall the Board. That is where the problem is. The board build settings are not read correctly. The compiler setting is missing.

Comment: I guess I can't do it through the USB

Comment: What has USB got to do with the board and compiler definition installation?  Just delete and reinstall the whole thing, not just the IDE. Delete all the boards and reinstall them.

Comment: I 've reinstalled with the same result :-(

Comment: Reinstalled the IDE, or reinstalled the boards / compilers etc packages?

Comment: [Please avoid posting duplicate questions on multiple SE sites](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34932494/error-compiling-arduino)

Answer (score 1):

Install Arduino SAMD Boards (32-bits ARM Cortex-M0+) board (using "Tools" -> "Board" -> "Boards Manager" menu).

Just search for "SAMD" in the search bar, choose the latest version and install.

Comment: Are you saying this fixed the problem?

Comment: yes !!!   indeed, this fixed the problem